# How to update progress bar using BeginInvoke method?

Tags: multithreading

I read answers of above few questions but did not work?
Following code i used to update the progress bar while doing another task

engine.ConvertProgressEvent += ConvertProgressEvent;
engine.Convert(inputFile, outputFile);

1 sentences will call the method ConvertProgressEvent

i.e

```
enter code here

  private void ConvertProgressEvent(object sender,ConvertProgressEventArgs e)
 {
 int percent = (int)(100 * (e.ProcessedDuration.TotalSeconds /              e.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds))
 percent = Math.Max(0, percent);
 percent = Math.Min(100, percennt);
 BeginInvoke(new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress), percent);
 } 

 private delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(int percent);
 private void UpdateProgress(int percent)
   {
   progressBar1.Value = percent;
   }
```

2 sentences is for converting one video file to another video file.And the progress bar has to update as per the processed conversion detail.

But this did not work progress bar is updated after the conversion complete.
please give me the solution for concurrent updating the progress Bar.

Comment: What happens if you inspect your code in the debugger?

Comment: Use the Debug + Windows + Threads debugging window.  Locate your main UI thread in the list  Double-click it and look at the Call Stack window.  It is doing something unwise, like waiting for the conversion to be completed.

Comment: yes this is waiting for conversion to complete.

Comment: plz tell me how to update the progress bar concurrent with conversion